# Changing data.frame column names with multiple inputs in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am hoping to change the name of either one particular column or all of the columns in each file that is entered by the user. So far I have tried this:

```
File.names<-(tk_choose.files(default="", caption="Files", multi=TRUE, filters=NULL, index=1))
Num.Files<-NROW(File.names)
test<-sapply(1:Num.Files,function(x){readLines(File.names[x])})
data<-lapply(1:Num.Files, function(x){data<-read.table(header=TRUE, text=test)})
new.names<-names(data)
new.names[[14]]<-'column14'
names(data) <- new.names
```

but I get:

```
Error in names(data) <- new.names : 
  'names' attribute [14] must be the same length as the vector [1]
Execution halted
```

The original column names are as such:

```
Targ  cov  av_cov  87A_cvg  87Ag  87Agr  87Agr  87A_gra  87A%_1   87A%_3   87A%_5   87A%_10  87A%_20  87A%_30 87A%_40   87A%_50 87A%_75 87A%_100
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to change the column names of multiple files in this manner? 
Thanks,
Steph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File.names<-(tk_choose.files(default="", caption="Choose your files", multi=TRUE, filters=NULL, index=1))
Num.Files<-NROW(File.names)
# read the files into a dummy variable
test<-sapply(1:Num.Files,function(x){readLines(File.names[x])})
# manipulate the first file
data<-read.table(header=T,text=test[1])
names(data)[14]<-'column14'
```

`tk_choose.files` allows you to select files. It stores these filenames in a character vector. You would then need to read the data into R. I have just used `readLines` to store all your data from the appropriate files for simplicity. You can use something like `read.tables` or `read.csv` directly.