# apply in R to change column names

Tags: r, apply

I am hoping to change one of the column names (the 14th column) in each of many files but I cannot figure how to go about it. I have tried multiple kinds of apply but that approach isn't working and I don't know where to start looking for another approach. Here is my code so far:

```
File.names<-(tk_choose.files(default="", caption="Files", multi=TRUE, filters=NULL, index=1))
Num.Files<-NROW(File.names)
test<-sapply(1:Num.Files,function(x){readLines(File.names[x])})
lapply(1:Num.Files, function(x){data<-read.table(header=TRUE, text=test)})
#This is the issue
names(data)[14]<-'column14'
names(data)
```

As I mentioned I tried varying types of apply but to no avail. Is there a different way of going about this? Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: I mentioned this in your last question, but the gynmastics you're going through with your two `sapply` then `lapply` steps are unnecessary.  Just use a single line of `lapply(File.names, read.table, sep='\t', header=TRUE)`. However, the reason it isn't working is because you read your data in inside a function but never assign that function's output to anything.  add a `data <- lapply(...` and you'll have a list of data.frames.  Then you need to `lapply` again to change the names.

Comment: @Justin If I try to consolidate the two lines into one, as you mention: data<-lapply(File.names, read.table, sep='\t', header=TRUE)
lapply(names(data)[14]<-'column14')
I get an error that states: Error in FUN("/home/Stephanie/Data/sample 2.ra.rc.bam.EXOME.DOC.sample_interval_summary"[[1L]],:more columns than column names

Comment: @Stephopolis it looks like your hitting your head against a wall and asking the same thing again and again (based on earlier questions).  Perhaps splitting up your code into the functional parts and then asking a specific question on just that part would help?  The more people that can reproduce the exact problem the more that will work on helping.

Comment: Then you've got some problems with your file formatting before it gets to R.  In any case, your `lapply` call needs to be assigned to something `data <- lapply(1:Num.Files, function(x){data<-read.table(header=TRUE, text=test)})`.  Then the answers below should work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing data.frame column names with multiple inputs in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936953/changing-data-frame-column-names-with-multiple-inputs-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the names out first, then alter, then assign as a group.  Like,

```
new.names <- names( data )
new.names[[14]] <- `column14`
names( data ) <- new.names
```

Comment: 'names' attribute [14] must be the same length as the vector [1] Could you explain this error to me?

Comment: Yeah, it means the length of `new.names` and your `data` vector don't match up.  When you assign new.names[[14]] and new.names is (let's say) 10 long, then new.names "grows" to 14 and when you attempt to assign the names back to the data the lengths no longer match and you get that error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `names` another `lapply`. E.g.:

```
l <- list(x=c(a=1, b=1), y=c(a=1, b=1))
l2 <- lapply(l, function(x) {
  names(x)[2] <- "d"
  return(x)
})

l2
#$x
#a d 
#1 1 
#
#$y
#a d 
#1 1
```